# Random Movement for multiple entities

Tags: java, random

I have this code for a arraylist of entities.

All the entities use the same random and so all of them move in the same direction. How can I change it so it generates a new random number for each entity?

```
public void moveFemale() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        random = rand.nextInt(99);
    }

    if (random >= 0 && random <= 25) {
        posX -= enemyWalkSpeed; // right
    }

    if (random >= 26 && random <= 50) {
        posX += enemyWalkSpeed; // left
    }

    if (random >= 51 && random <= 75) {
        posY -= enemyWalkSpeed; // up
    }

    if (random >= 76 && random <= 100) {
        posY += enemyWalkSpeed; // down
    }
}
```

Is this correct?

```
public void moveFemale() {
    for (Female female: GameFrame.females){

        female.lastChangedDirectionTime += elapsedTime;

        if (female.lastChangedDirectionTime >= CHANGE_DIRECTION_TIME)
        {
            female.lastChangedDirectionTime = 0;

            random = rand.nextInt(100);

            if (random >= 0 && random <= 25) {
                posX -= enemyWalkSpeed; // right
            }

            if (random >= 26 && random <= 50) {
                posX += enemyWalkSpeed; // left
            }

            if (random >= 51 && random <= 75) {
                posY -= enemyWalkSpeed; // up
            }

            if (random >= 76 && random <= 100) {
                posY += enemyWalkSpeed; // down
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry -- what is the purpose of your for loop? I don't think you need that? What does the 1000 refer to?

Comment: its a crude timer that only allows random to generate a new number after 1000 has been hit. I know its bad but I can't figure out a timer.

Comment: Ouch, that's bound to cause issues. Let me think.. what are you trying to achieve with that, game-mechanics-wise? Is this to change direction only after some time has passed?

Comment: Yeah but anyway... How would I fix the random movement? All the entities move the same way. I honestly have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entities ("females") need to have a public member on them, something like

```
public int lastChangedDirectionTime = 0; //milliseconds
```

You also need some time interval at which you want them to change direction, set up as a constant:

```
public final int CHANGE_DIRECTION_PERIOD = 1000; //milliseconds
```

As each game loop goes by, get the amount of time that has elapsed since the last game loop iteration (if you don't have this value, comment!), and do

```
for (Entity entity : entities) //every one!
{
    entity.lastChangeDirectionTime += timeElapsed; //presumably both in the same time unit eg. seconds

}
```

As soon as you've done the addition, do this:

```
if (entity.lastChangeDirectionTime >= CHANGE_DIRECTION_PERIOD)
{
    entity.lastChangeDirectionTime = 0;

    //do your directional change logic, here.
}
```

I'm not 100% sure of your structure so you'll need to figure out where to slot these into your code.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, but I get this error when try to to for(Females female : females): Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable                                          I have no idea what this means at all, I've never actually dealt with this particular for loop before.

Comment: Not to worry. First I see your typename is Females with an 'S', is that right? Secondly a for-each loop like I have there is just the same as saying `for (int c = 0; c < entities.length; c++) { Entity entity == entities[i]; //etc. }` No difference, for-each is just a bit quicker to type.

Comment: ok so if my arraylist is in my GameFrame class, the for loop would be like this?: `for (GameFrame.Female female:females)` Is that correct?

Comment: My arraylist in gameframe: `static ArrayList<Female> females = new ArrayList<Female>();`

Comment: Ah, you have an `ArrayList`. Yes, this is why I said, "Females with an 'S'" right? Because you had a typo, before. Try again with `for (Female female : females)` That should work fine, because `ArrayList` adheres to `java.lang.Iterable` as mentioned before. Read that colon as "in", in your mind, and it will make sense as you type it.

Comment: So what does timeElapsed equal then? Can I use do `time++` inside a loop and use that for timeElasped? Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: You're welcome. OK, `timeElapsed`: Do you know how many frames per second your game is running at? Yes / No? (And, you must never do timing like you suggest there. It will break everything.)

Comment: That's the thing, I have a basic timer set up in my GameFrame class : `mainTimer = new Timer(10, this);
  mainTimer.start();` However, I have no idea how to get this to return a variable.

Comment: No, that's absolutely great. OK, so that `Timer(10, this)` is just saying that you have a 10 millisecond fixed timestep. There are 1000 ms in a second, so your fps/update rate is 1000/10 = 100 frames per second, just for interest's sake. So you can use 10 as the value for timeElapsed; on every update, we know 10ms have passed since the last update, right? Take it away!

Comment: Very important: Are you using milliseconds everywhere? Just make sure you are. I've changed my code for that, too. Note, I'm off to bed. GLHF :)

Comment: Its a little buggy, as in some of the entities don't move at all, but you sir deserve a huge damn medal for all this! Thanks!

Comment: Could you take a quick look at my final code I put in the question please? Just to make sure I did everything right :P